# Will magnetic pedals interfere with ebike batteries or motors?

Tags: pedals, electric-bike

I am wondering if magnetic pedals would induce current in mid-drive ebike motors or batteries.  I am assuming for theoretical purposes, they would, because all oscillating magnetic fields induce a current in everything conductive within their lightcone, but for all practical purposes, the effect would be so negligible as to be unmeasurable, but I don't really want to do the calculations myself.  Is there any research out there on this, or can anyone do any napkin calculations?

Comment: Magnetic pedals weren't something I'd come across before - they're an interesting concept for foot retention though I can't see me ever trying them

Comment: If you're using the word "lightcone", you're required to do the math.

Comment: I'll just comment that magnetic pedals have been tried as many times as there are reasons they haven't been widely adopted (i.e., many times and reason).

Comment: Some e-bikes have a reed-contact, activated by the a permanent magnet in the spokes and possibly an similar sensor to detect pedal motion like bike-computers had. The cleat retention might interfere with these.

Comment: @PaulH GCN on YouTube has a video on magnetic cleats in a show on cycling inventions that never came into general use.

Comment: For those not in the know, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone

Comment: @Paul H What are the reasons?  They seem perfect for regular people who aren't racing who just want their feet to stick to their pedals better but who don't want them completely attached and who want to be able to use their pedals with regular shoes at times or let their friends use them with regular shoes.

Comment: @Carel I love GCN!  I'd enjoy watching that video, but I have so far been unsuccessful at finding it.  GMBN had a recent video in which they mentioned them, but they dismissed them out of hand and did not actually try them.

Comment: @kloddant I'd consider half clips for that use case (but I've got SPDs on all my current bikes, some of which allow limited use with normal shoes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They won't interfere with the batteries (which aren't sensitive to magnets) or the motor (which contains stronger moving magnetic fields). Anyway even in the worst case both are a good few cm away and magnetic fields reduce quickly with distance.

Even wiring run along the downtube is reasonably well separated from the pedals, and it takes a lot to induce a measurable current in a straight wire with even a strong permanent magnet (I've tried - even a coil has trouble picking up much unless far closer than your setup would suggest). A problematic current would be even harder to induce.

There's a slim chance they might interfere with a magnetic cadence sensor in the cranks, which some electric bikes use to sense pedalling to know when to assist. You may be able to whether a particular model uses that sort of sensor.

Comment: *Maybe* they could interfere with Shimano’s electric shifting system which uses wires for the signals.

Comment: @Michael I'd be very surprised. You have try quite hard to sense a magnet. If electronic shifting was that sensitive it would have trouble with the field from the current in the motor wiring,which is much closer as well as stronger (and pulsed faster as the motor uses PWM to control the speed)